# Django Rest Model serializers and model inheritance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I write custom model of user in my app. Application components are:

- Django 1.8
- Django REST framework 3.2.4
- Django-allauth 0.23.0
- Django-rest-auth 0.5.

Code of user model you can see [pythonfiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com/for-so-question). When I go to Django-rest-auth registration endpoint I see this error:

> ValueError at `/rest-auth/registration/`
>   Cannot use ModelSerializer with Abstract Models.

This is settings are relating with Django-rest-auth:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL='authservice.MyUser'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD='email'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD='email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION='mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True    
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS=2
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Maybe you have associated the serializer model to an unwanted abstract model by mistake ?

Answer (score 3):

to the best of my knowledge, DRF does not currently support the use of `ModelSerializer` with Abstract Models, however, you can use `Serializer`.

A simple implementation would be something (not tested) like:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    student  = serializers.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then in your view, you can manually save. Something like...

```
class MyUserView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Also, for the discussion about whether or not to include this use of `ModelSerializer` checkout https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2630 and https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/84

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When i more careful  study local var values in post-morten django debugger  i see that problem was related with rest_framework.authtoken,when i reinstall DRF anf rewrite INSTALL_APPS list all become ok

Comment: this was helping indeed